# How to access a form function from a different class

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, desktop-application

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{

    public disp(string strVal)
     {
                   lbl1.text = strVal;
      }     

     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            class1 cl  = new class1;
            cl.Show1("test",this);

        }

}
```

---------------- Class ------------

```
public class class1

{
 private Form  frm1;

    public void  Show1(string xName , object xfrmObj)
    {
        frm1 = (form) xfrmObj;
        frm1.disp(xName );  // here I am getting error .
    }

}
```

------------------------------------------/

here i am trying to access 'disp' function from class and i have  pass 'form1'  as a object ,  but i am getting error

The error message that I am getting is

> Error  3
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'disp' 
>   and no extension method 'disp' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found 
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

this syntax in vb.net is working perfect.

please help me.....

Rajesh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to cast `frm1 = (Form1)xfrmObj;` instead of casting it to `form` in your `Show1(xName,xfrmObj)` method.

**EDIT:** OP has stated in a comment that he needs this to work for several different forms.
You can make all your forms implement the same `Interface`, like so:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, ICanDisplay
{ 
    public void disp(string strVal) 
    { //...
    } 
}

public partial class Form2 : Form, ICanDisplay
{
    public void disp(string strVal) 
    { //...
    }
}

public interface ICanDisplay
{
    void disp(string strVal);
}
```

then, change your method so it casts to ICanDisplay:

```
public class class1
{
private Form  frm1;

public void Show1(string xName , object xfrmObj)
{
    frm1 = (ICanDisplay) xfrmObj;
    frm1.disp(xName);
}
```

}

**However, as @Heinzi has noted, you should change your Show1-method to the following:**

```
public void Show1(string xName, IDisplayForm xfrmObj)
{
    xfrmObj.Disp(xName);
}
```

this will make the cast entirely unnecessary. The next step is to *select meaningful names for your variables, functions and classes*.

Comment: you're welcome. if this works, please mark this post as the answer to your question.

Comment: thanks your reply... its working perfect. but this function access different forms.so i can't cast the form name. any other option please?. Rajesh

Comment: @RajeshAbraham I've edited my answer to make it possible to call the function on several forms.

Comment: If using c#4.0: dynamic frm2 = xfrmObj;frm2.disp(xName);

Comment: yes, RedHat's solution should also work, at the expense of type safety. This is not one of the recommended uses of `dynamic`...

Comment: Dynamic is manaically clever.. but really you should avoid except where its appropriate. This is not a case where its appropriate, the "right" answer is to use an interface

Comment: hi codesparkle.. thank you very much.. it is working perfect...thanks your interest... you are great.. rajesh

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you Rajesh. Please mark this as the correct answer if you are satisfied. @heinzi thanks!